# check if key exist in object javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have object in which if key does not exist set to null using javascript.

If the key doesnot exist in object `obj` like `ccy` does not exist `cn` `MY` and `CA`, how to assign and set to null using javascript.

```
var obj=[{
  "cn": "TH",
  "lang": "thai",
  "bank": "yes",
  "ccy": "THB"
},{
   "cn": "MY",
   "lang": "malay",
},{
   "cn": "CA",
   "lang": "english",
   "bank": "yes"
}]

render(){
  obj.map(e=>
  return html`
    <h1>${e.cn}</h1>
    <h5>${e.lang}</h5>
    <h6>${e.ccy}</h6>
`
 )
}
```

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: `${e.ccy === undefined ? null : e.ccy}`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for reply, in my `obj` since dynamic how to check the key name itself exist

Comment: changed the comment, so perhaps it's more clear? Though the answer below is more correct

Comment: Wouldn't `<h6>${e.ccy || null}</h6>` do the trick?

Comment: @spender, what if e.ccy were the value `0` (though given the sample data it probably would be a string, so your suggestion would work)

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I considered this. Looking at the data, it seems the `e.ccy` is going to be of type `string|undefined`, so this *should* be fine, unless `""` is a potential value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to write default fallback values into template and want to keep template clean, you could also preprocess data and set missing values before rendering:

```js
var obj = [{
  "cn": "TH",
  "lang": "thai",
  "bank": "yes",
  "ccy": "THB"
}, {
  "cn": "MY",
  "lang": "malay",
}, {
  "lang": "english",
  "bank": "yes"
}]

obj = obj.map(({
  cn = null,
  ccy = null,
  ...rest
}) => Object.assign(rest, { cn, ccy }))

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do, as long as you can be sure `e.ccy` won't be falsy (`false`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, or `NaN`) is to use the logical OR operator `||`:

```
${e.ccy || null}
```

Comment: I know @Ele - see the first line of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the operator `in` to check if the key exists as follow:

The operator `in` is the most secure way for avoiding wrong checks on falsy values.

`{"ccy" in e ? e.ccy : null}`

Comment: or `${'ccy' in e ? e.ccy : null}` to fit with the code OP has added

Comment: you wouldn't (necessarily) need to assign it to `e` though

Answer (score 0):

Any key not defined in a javascript object will be considered to be undefined so you could either check

```
(typeof obj.ccy === "undefined") ? null : obj.ccy;
(obj.ccy == undefined) ? null : obj.ccy;
```

If you are not familiar with ternary expressions. You could also write the above as this.

```
if(obj.ccy == undefined){
   obj.ccy = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to check if a given key exists in an object.

```
if(!obj[0].hasOwnProperty('cn')) {
    obj[o].cn = null
}
```

or

```
if(typeof obj[0].cn === 'undefined') {
    obj[0].cn = null;
}
```

or

```
if(obj[0].cn === undefined) {
    obj[0].cn = null;
}
```

The latter two are very similar in this case, `typeof` is usually used when you want to check if a variable is defined and accessible in the code.

Now the real example is like so:

```
var missing = ['cn', 'ccy'];
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < missing.length; j++) {
        if(!obj[i].hasOwnProperty(missing[j])) {
            obj[i][missing[j]] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = [...Object.keys(obj[0]),...Object.keys(obj[1]),...Object.keys(obj[2])]
for(let i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
 for(let k=0;k<q.length;k++){
   if(!(q[k] in obj[i])){
    obj[i][q[k]] = null
  }
 }
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Please add a comment explaining how your code fixes the issue to improve this answer.

Comment: It can be used in array of objects containing variable keys in any objects ,not necessarily in first index and you need not give the names of the keys also.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.